# How to use Hall's theorem to show a necessary and sufficient condition for some problem (modified marriages problem)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I undestand Hall's theorem but I'm not sure how to apply it to problems. I have such problem which I believe needs to be solved using Halls' theorem.

Problem:

We have a group of *n* girls and *m* boys. Show that a necessary and sufficient condition for *k* girls to find a husband (inside the group) is that each *r* girls know minimum *k+r-n* boys.

This almost screams to use Hall's theorem but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hall's theorem tells you something about finding a matching of size $n$ (i.e. a husband for all $n$ girls), while here you want to consider matchings of size at least $k$. The trick for applying Hall's theorem in this situation is to add $n-k$ new "boy" vertices, each of them connected to every "girl" vertex.

You should first check that a matching of size at least $k$ in the original graph can be extended to a matching of size $n$ in this new graph, and conversely, a matching of size $n$ in this graph gives a matching of size at least $k$ in the original graph. Then you can verify that the necessary and sufficient condition given is equivalent to Hall's condition in this "augmented" graph.

Do tell me if you need more help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Why should I check that a matching of size at least k in the original graph can be extended to a matching of size n in this new graph, and conversely...? What does it give me?

Comment: It shows that there is a matching of size at least $k$ in the original graph if and only if there is a matching of size $n$ in the new graph; and the latter is true if and only if Hall's condition is satisfied by the new graph.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that matching of size n in the new graph gives a matching of size at least k in the original graph?

Comment: That would only give you that the condition given is sufficient. For necessity, you need the other direction as well. Granted, this is the easier direction and you can show it directly if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now.

Comment: Hi, in this solution I wanted to show that we can transit from one matching to another. Now I face "Harem problem" and I believe that it can be solved in a similar manner. But I have a question. Is it possible to get a proper matching in a harem problem? Since 4 woan can be married to one man then that would mean that in a matching 4 "female" verticles would be connected to one "male" vertex.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "Harem problem". At any rate, you should probably ask this as a separate question on this site - I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Sure, I'll ask another one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118961/discussion-between-karol-and-daniel-g).